# Electric dipolar moment of a half wave antenna

Tags: electromagnetism

We have an antenna ($\lambda = L/2$), of length $L$ with a current density:

$$\vec j=I\sin [k(|z|-L/2)]\delta(x)\delta(y)e^{-i\omega t}\hat e_z$$

I want to calculate its electric dipole moment. I get a differential of q by integrating over time so $dq=ij/\omega dz$

And then would it be: $\vec p=\int_{-L/2}^{L/2}dq\hat e_z$?

Is that correct?

Comment: What is "half way"? Half way between here and there?

Comment: @Georg Sorry, half wave

Comment: λ=L/2 means that L= λ * 2, which is a "twowave" antenna.

Comment: @Georg never mind, the name is irrelevant. It's a wire with that current.